# external app using python instance created by virtualenv? (windows)

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

Is it possible to make 3rd party external executable to use instance of python created by virtualenv? Thing is application i am using wants to use modified and old version of pyside, and i need to use new version for my own needs. Virtualenv should solve the problem if only i could make this 3rd party application use instance of python other than default one. -Is that possible?

Comment: It is application-specific e.g., [pyUno](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=36370&p=166783)

Comment: What's this 'external' executable? How exactly does it call the Python stuff?

Comment: it imports python26.dll and does the magic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You just need to call the activation script prior starting your program (installed as `Scripts/activate.bat` under Windows).

Comment: for some reason it does not work this way. could it be that activate.bat has effect only on py scripts?

Comment: @rndbit virtualenv changes the python interpreter (and sets corresponding `PYTHONPATH`).

Comment: it is unlikely that a package that has C extension modules such as PySide would work on a different Python version, see [pep-384](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0384/)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yeah, he would need to install correct version of the interpreter...

Comment: Turns out activate.bat was not setting PYTHONPATH for some reason. However if it did - it should have worked. I hexed bundled python26.dll and changed it to use custom environmental variable instead of PYTHONPATH, set that variable to point to dir made by virtualenv and it worked. Thanks guys! :)